# I am trying to write a function which reads data from bigtable and convert ByteString to Genric record

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to write a BigTableAvroFn function, which reads the bigtable row and using apache beam it converts into Avro generic record .How do i convert row data to genric record ?

```
pipeline.apply("Read from Bigtable", read)
    .apply("Transform to Avro", ParDo(new BigtableToAvroFn()));

    return pipeline.run();
}
```

static class BigtableToAvroFn extends
      DoFn {

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    Row row = c.element();
}
```

Since I am a Beginner to Apache Beam, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Updated the question .

Comment: You might be better served by brushing up on the basics of `Avro` and `Cloud Bigtable` before diving into this `Apache Beam` use case. Try the [Avro Getting Started](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html) and [Cloud Bigtable Java Hello World](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/hello-world/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/bigtable/helloworld/HelloWorld.java), then branch out into some of the other examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading from Bigtable into Avro, maybe you could try to use the [Google provided Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloudbigtabletoavrofile) for Bigtable->Avro, you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/BigtableToAvro.java).